# Better Crypto Currency for trading

Tags: trading, buy-bitcoins, ethereum, sell-bitcoins, crypto-2.0

Can anyone suggest me which crypto currency is better for trading? Is it Bitcoin or Ethereum?

Prices in USD as of 21/08/2017 and time 18:03 (UTC+05:30):

1. Bitcoin = $4041.53 or
2. Ethereum = $325.76

Comment: Hello iamjayp, investment advice is off-topic on our site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Volatility is higher in Bitcoin right now. But ETH rose recently as well. It depends on how you define better for your purposes and how the markets will behave which is always difficult to predict.

Comment: Okay you are correct. Bitcoin is extremely volatile since, price of Bitcoin is $3978.21 as of 22/08/2017 , time : 18:09 (UTC+05:30)